# boto3 Get a resource from a client

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

The AWS Library for python (boto) has two different types of interfaces for working with AWS, a low level `client` and a higher level more pythonic `resource`.

Parts of my code use one, while other parts use the other.

Getting a `client` from a `resource` is found from the docs.

```
# Create the resource
sqs_resource = boto3.resource('sqs')

# Get the client from the resource
sqs = sqs_resource.meta.client
```

My questions is if have the client `sqs`, how do I get a `boto3.resource` from this?

(I can't simply just call `boto3.resource('sqs')` because the client has other things, such as credentials already attached to it, the resource for some design reason tries to fetch the AWS credentials from a bunch of places I don't want it to, I'd like it to use whatever credentials/account is set on the client)

Comment: See also https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/747 which would enable you to get it, if implemented.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way to do this. If you want to use both, you should create a resource and use the embedded client. You can instantiate a resource with the exact same configuration as a client. The underlying client for the resource is created in the exact same way. The only difference between a resource's client and a client created with the exact same parameters is that the resource client adds 'Resource' to the user-agent.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should create resource and client separately as below:

```
import boto3
sqs_resource = boto3.resource("sqs")
sqs_client = boto3.client("sqs")

print dir(sqs_resource)
print dir(sqs_client)
```

Output:

```
[u'Message', u'Queue', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', u'create_queue', 'get_available_subresources', u'get_queue_by_name', 'meta', u'queues']
['_PY_TO_OP_NAME', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_cache', '_client_config', '_convert_to_request_dict', '_endpoint', '_force_path_style_s3_addressing', '_force_virtual_style_s3_addressing', '_get_waiter_config', '_loader', '_make_api_call', '_register_handlers', '_register_s3_specific_handlers', '_request_signer', '_response_parser', '_serializer', '_service_model', u'add_permission', 'can_paginate', u'change_message_visibility', u'change_message_visibility_batch', u'create_queue', u'delete_message', u'delete_message_batch', u'delete_queue', 'generate_presigned_url', 'get_paginator', u'get_queue_attributes', u'get_queue_url', 'get_waiter', u'list_dead_letter_source_queues', u'list_queues', 'meta', u'purge_queue', u'receive_message', u'remove_permission', u'send_message', u'send_message_batch', u'set_queue_attributes', 'waiter_names']
```

From above output, you will always get client from resource as sqs_resource.meta.client.

But vice-versa is not possible.

Instead, create resource and client both and use whatever you required.
Please let me know if this is useful.