# How to capture botocore's NoSuchKey exception?

Tags: python, botocore

I'm trying to write "good" python and capture a S3 no such key error with this:

```
session = botocore.session.get_session()
client = session.create_client('s3')
try:
    client.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=FILE)
except NoSuchKey as e:
    print >> sys.stderr, "no such key in bucket"
```

But NoSuchKey isn't defined and I can't trace it to the import I need to have it defined.

`e.__class__` is `botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchKey` but `from botocore.errorfactory import NoSuchKey` gives an error and `from botocore.errorfactory import *` doesn't work either and I don't want to capture a generic error.

Comment: For exceptions like `botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchKey`, modeled exceptions needs to be accessed through the client object. So rather than having `botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchKey` you need `client.exceptions.NoSuchKey`

Answer (score 242, accepted):

```
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

try:
    response = self.client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    return json.loads(response["Body"].read())
except ClientError as ex:
    if ex.response['Error']['Code'] == 'NoSuchKey':
        logger.info('No object found - returning empty')
        return dict()
    else:
        raise
```

Comment: I prefer this technique (inspect the error.response dict) because it is more Type friendly compared to the alternative `client.exceptions.NoSuchKey` technique; the python type system has no idea about the class structure of the latter. I am aware of some add-on type annotation solutions but I don't like that approach either, its too much hard work.

Comment: I found its path when importing aioboto3 (async boto3):  aioboto3.session.boto3.exceptions.botocore.errorfactory.ClientError

Comment: I am getting `ex.response['Error']['Code'] == "404"`, is this the same?

Answer (score 113):

Using botocore 1.5, it looks like the client handle exposes the exception classes:

```
session = botocore.session.get_session()
client = session.create_client('s3')
try:
    client.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=FILE)
except client.exceptions.NoSuchKey as e:
    print >> sys.stderr, "no such key in bucket"
```

Comment: I'm opting for this one, as it's newer and also less generic.

You can find some comments on GitHub regarding this method:
https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1262#issuecomment-329314670

Comment: If you forgot to scroll like me: If you're using the high-level resource (`s3 = boto3.resource("s3")`), you can access the client and thus the Exception via `s3.meta.client.exceptions.NoSuchKey`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38581465/boto3-get-a-resource-from-a-client

Answer (score 57):

In boto3, I was able to access the exception in resource's meta client.

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_object = s3.Object(bucket_name, key)

try:
    content = s3_object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
except s3.meta.client.exceptions.NoSuchKey:
    print("no such key in bucket")
```

Answer (score 47):

I think the most elegant way to do this is in Boto3 is

```
session = botocore.session.get_session()
client = session.create_client('s3')

try:
    client.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=FILE)
except client.exceptions.NoSuchKey:
    print("no such key in bucket")
```

The documentation on error handling seems sparse, but the following prints the error codes this works for:

```
import botocore.session

session = botocore.session.get_session()
client = session.create_client('s3')
try:
    client.exceptions.notexist
except AttributeError as err:
    print(err)
```

> < botocore.errorfactory.S3Exceptions object at 0x105e08c50 > object has no attribute notexist. Valid exceptions are: BucketAlreadyExists, BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou, InvalidObjectState, NoSuchBucket, NoSuchKey, NoSuchUpload, ObjectAlreadyInActiveTierError, ObjectNotInActiveTierError

Comment: For reasons that may be unrelated, when I trap Exceptions in this way, they do not propagate. (?)

Comment: If you trap it, you silence it. You then need to raise it again like "raise err"