# Properly catch boto3 Errors

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, exception, boto3

I am developing a django app which communicates with several Amazon Web Services.

So far I am having trouble dealing with and catching exceptions thrown by the boto3 client. What I am doing seems unnecessarily tedious:

Example:

```
client = boto3.client('sns')
client.create_platform_endpoint(PlatformApplicationArn=SNS_APP_ARN, Token=token)
```

this might throw an `botocore.errorfactory.InvalidParameterException` if e.g. the token is bad.

```
client.get_endpoint_attributes(EndpointArn=endpoint_arn)
```

might throw an `botocore.errorfactory.NotFoundException`.

First, I can't find these Errors anywhere in code, so they are probably generated somewhere. Bottom line: I can't import it and catch it as usual.

Second, I found one way to catch the error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42975609/how-to-capture-botocores-nosuchkey-exception) using:

```
try:
    # boto3 stuff
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'NotFound':
        # handle exception
    else:
        raise e
```

But I have to remove the `Exception` part of the error name. Seems very random and I have no clue whether I would remove the `Error` in `botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError` if I wanted to catch that one. So it's hard to generalize.

Another way to catch the error is using the boto3 client object I got:

```
try:
    # boto3 stuff
except client.exceptions.NotFoundException as e:
    # handle exception
```

This seems the cleanest way so far. But I don't always have the boto3 client object at hand where I want to catch the error. Also I am still only trying things out, so it's mostly guess work.

Does anybody know how boto3 errors are supposed to be handled?

Or can point me towards some coherent documentation which mentions the errors above? Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/develop/boto3/exceptions.py#L19

Comment: This is the first place I looked, please read my first point again. The errors don't show up anywhere in code!

Comment: There is existing discussion on very similar subject, may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068055/boto3-python-and-how-to-handle-errors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle errors with boto3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068055/how-to-handle-errors-with-boto3)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You've summarized the situation well. The old `boto` had a simple hardcoded approach to supporting AWS APIs. `boto3`, in what appears to be an attempt to reduce the overhead of keeping Python client synced with evolving features on the various apis, has been more squishy around exceptions, so the ClientError approach you outlined above used to be the canonical way.

In 2017 they introduced the second mechanism you highlight: 'modeled' exceptions available on the client.

I am not familiar with SNS but in my experience with other AWS products, the ClientError naming matches up with the HTTP apis, which tend to be well documented. So I would start here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/Welcome.html

It looks like the new-style modeled exceptions are generated from service definition files that live in botocore module. I can't find any documentation about it, but go browse around the AWS service models in https://github.com/boto/botocore/tree/master/botocore/data.

Also, it's good to know that if you are not (in contrast to OP's code) dealing directly with the low-level client, but instead are using a high-level AWS `ServiceResource` object, a low-level client is still easily available at `my_service_resource.meta.client` so you can handle exceptions like this:

```
try:
    my_service_resource.do_stuff()
except my_service_resource.meta.client.exceptions.NotFoundException as e:
    # handle exception
```

Comment: Thank you, that documentation link was exactly what I needed! So it seems that the first option is better, as it uses the documented exception names. `NotFound` exception is documented, `NotFoundException` is not. I guess this is part of the hardcoding / keeping in sync issue you mentioned? Because if not, I do not understand where that exception name originates from as it does not appear anywhere in the API docs.

Comment: I decided to go looking. Turns out there is a kind of service discovery mechanism going on, based on definitions stored in a declarative way within botocore. Check out https://github.com/boto/botocore/tree/master/botocore/data. I'll update the answer to reflect this discovery.

Comment: I don't have exceptions under meta, they are on the client directly so `my_server_resource.exceptions.NotFoundException`

Comment: @AaronMcMillin boto exposes two kinds of clients. One is the low-level Client object, as the OP is using and as you too are using. You get one of these (let's use s3 as an example) by calling `boto3.client('s3')`. There is also a higher level 'Service Resource' object, which is also reasonable to call a client in the generic sense of the word. You'd get one like so: `s3 = boto3.resource('s3')`. Boto docs tend to point users towards the resource object for simple use cases, so I thought it was worth calling out the difference.

Comment: @benauthor do we need to check statuscode in response after do_stuff? like `if resp["ResponseMetadata"].get("HTTPStatusCode") != 200` if I am capturing response as well `resp = my_service_resource.do_stuff() `

Comment: This doesn't work if you want to handle a `NoSuchBucket` error from `boto3.client('s3').head_bucket` because it actually returns a `ClientError`, despite what the docs say. See https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1262#issuecomment-1011266230.

Comment: @BigMcLargeHuge bummer. thanks for calling this out. based on the response in that thread it sounds like this may be the case for any boto method wrapping a HEAD call. Though boto now does have docs describing modeled exceptions (they did not back in '18), those docs carry an alarming caveat "Catching exceptions through ClientError and parsing for error codes is still the best way to catch all service-side exceptions and errors." lolsob?

Answer (score 9):

Use Boto3 exceptions: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/97944/boto3.exceptions

```
client = boto3.client('logs')
try:
   client.create_log_group(logGroupName=LOG_GROUP)
except client.exceptions.ResourceAlreadyExistsException:
   pass
```

Comment: Do you mean ` except client.exceptions.ResourceExistsException:` ?